# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::insert_item() in D:\wamp\www\registration\application\controllers\pages.php on line 37

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to CI and I have just started to code. I am making a simple contact form and got this error.

```
Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::insert_item() in 
D:\wamp\www\registration\application\controllers\pages.php on line 37
```

Here is the code of my controller.php

```
<?php class Pages extends CI_Controller { public function view($page = 'home'){

if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
}

$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

$this->load->model('user_model');

//$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
//$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);} public function data_submitted(){
$name = $this->input->get('name');
$email = $this->input->get('email');
$mobile = $this->input->get('mobile');
$address = $this->input->get('address');
$gender = $this->input->get('gender');

$data1 = array(
    'name'=> $name,
    'email'=>$email,
    'mobile'=>$mobile,
    'address'=>$address,
    'gender'=>$gender
);
//$this->db->set($data1);
$this->user_model->insert($data1); } } ?>
```

and here is full code of my model

```
<?php class User_model extends CI_Model { private $item; function __construct(){
/* Call the Model constructor */
parent::__construct(); }
function insert_item($item){
/*$this->table = "contact";
$this->item = $item;
*/
//$dbconnect = $this->load->database();
$this->db->insert("contact", $item);} }
```

Comment: After trying everything Please remove this line $this->user_model->insert($data1); and simply write $this->db->insert("contact", $data1); LOL :D :D

Comment: And  what is the result Success or fail  ???

Comment: fail, can you please explain

Comment: Do **echo $this->db->last_query();** and after getting the query go to mysql and run your query there me be some mysql issue :)

Comment: I guess that  'mobile'=>$mobile could be the problem maybe 'mobile' is defined as **int** in your database and you are passing an string.

Comment: thanxx for ur valueable comment...... Got the solution.. ty again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is referencing the `db` library:

```
$this->db->insert_item($data1);
```

However, the `insert_item()` method only exists in your model!

It should look something like this:

```
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $this->my_model->insert_item($data1);
```

Edit here to take into account your controller code.

Assuming the `user_model` has already been loaded, and that the `user_model` contains the method `insert_item()` you want to change

```
$this->user_model->insert($data1);
```

to

```
$this->user_model->insert_item($data1);
```

---

Having seen your complete controller and model code...

Your controller:

You are loading the user model in your `view()` method, but from what I can see you're not actually using it. You are however using the model in `data_submitted()` but it was never loaded there. You were also using `insert` rather than `insert_item()`. Here is the corrected code for the controller.

```
public function view($page = 'home') {
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    //$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

public function data_submitted(){
    $name = $this->input->get('name');
    $email = $this->input->get('email');
    $mobile = $this->input->get('mobile');
    $address = $this->input->get('address');
    $gender = $this->input->get('gender');

    $data1 = array(
        'name'=> $name,
        'email'=>$email,
        'mobile'=>$mobile,
        'address'=>$address,
        'gender'=>$gender
    );

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->user_model->insert_item($data1);
}
```

Your model:

There seemed to be some code that did absolutely nothing. I have stripped that out and the following code should work.

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct(){
        /* Call the Model constructor */
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function insert_item($item){
        $this->db->insert("contact", $item);
    }
}
```

As a side note - can you see how easy the code is to read now? Make sure you use proper indentation as it massively increases the readability of code.

Comment: I used ur code but this error is occured.  Undefined property: Pages::$user_model

Comment: Can I see the error? Can you supply the full code for your model and controller please?

Comment: ok.. I am commenting my whole cod of model controller and view

Comment: It would be best to update your question with the full code of your model and controller.

Comment: May be  private $item;(In model) Crating problem ?? Is it Possible that passing the same **$item** could effect the insert in any way ??

Comment: $item should not affect the insert as it wasn't being used.

Comment: I have amended my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You have used

```
$this->db->insert_item($data1);
```

but `insert_item` is a model function.

Load model and then call via model like below :

```
$this->load->model('Blog');
$this->Blog->get_last_ten_entries();
```

Comment: @SonuBamniya : Try my answer and check.

Comment: @SonuBamniya Have you called function via model?

Comment: Undefined property: Pages::$user_model this error occured now

Comment: In my comment I have posted my whole controller code

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you are calling your model->function correctly. The naming conventions are off between the 2 (they have to be called as they appear in your model)
last call in data_submitted() should be: $this->user_model->insert_item($data1); as per below

Controller:

```
<?php class Pages extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}

public function view($page = 'home')
{

    if (!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
    //$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

public function data_submitted()
{
    $name = $this->input->get('name');
    $email = $this->input->get('email');
    $mobile = $this->input->get('mobile');
    $address = $this->input->get('address');
    $gender = $this->input->get('gender');

    $data1 = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'mobile' => $mobile,
        'address' => $address,
        'gender' => $gender
    );
    //$this->db->set($data1);
    $this->user_model->insert_item($data1);
}
} ?>
```

Model:

```
<?php class User_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
{
    /* Call the Model constructor */
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

private $item;

function insert_item($item)
{
    /*$this->table = "contact";
    $this->item = $item;
    */
    //$dbconnect = $this->load->database();

    $this->db->insert("contact", $item);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? have you made any other code changes? how are you posting the data in the view? you are using $this->input->get() so this would be trying to get data from your URI (pages.php?name=bob&email=bob@example.com, etc . If you are sending the data from post method, you need to retrieve it by using $this->input->post()

Comment: Undefined property: Pages::$user_model

Comment: and Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_item() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\registration\application\controllers\pages.php on line 36

Comment: I m using get method

Comment: I have updated my answer, some of the formatting you were using posting was questionable as to what was commented and what wasnt, what is provided above should work for you (it works locally for me)